# Match-set via libiptc

Tags: iptables, netfilter, ipset

Could anyone share any examples that use match-set for iptables via the libiptc library?

I have tried using the iptables v1.4.21 and the code from https://bani.com.br/2012/05/programmatically-managing-iptables-rules-in-c-iptc/

However this does not contain the match-set extension and there is no clear man page documentation regarding its usage. Does anyone have any examples that use match-set?